# Resizing debug bar freezes Xcode 4.3.3 on Retina MacBook Pro

Tags: xcode, xcode4, xcode4.3

I have been using Xcode 4.3.3 for a few days on my retina mac (Lion, of course). At work I always have my Xcode window on a Cinema Display and have never experienced any problems.  However, I threw an Xcode window onto the pro's display and tried to resize the debug bar - Xcode hangs. 99-100% CPU and the cursor turns into the rainbow wheel of death.  I tried deleting everything in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData` because that has cleared up all of my issues with Xcode in the past, but that's a no go. I want to do some iOS development when I am not at work, but this makes it pretty hard to do since I don't have a cinema display or other monitor at home.

Here's the sample from the Activity Monitor:

http://pastebin.com/2Suz1b9v

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. By default, Apple opens Xcode in a resolution optimized for the Retina Display.  You can force XCode (or any other application) to open with a lower resolution by doing the following:

- Quit the application if it is currently open.
- In the Finder, choose Applications from the Go menu.
- In the Applications folder that opens, click the application's icon so it is highlighted.
- Choose Get Info from the File menu.
- Place a checkmark next to "Open in Low Resolution" to enable Low Resolution mode.
- Close the window and double click the Application to reopen it.

And it works!

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue.  Nice fix, let's hope Apple patches this bug soon!

Comment: @brozak: I am thinking about upgrading to Mac Retina - can you give me an idea if Xcode4.3 is faster than on any previous model? I have a 2.4 GHz Core i5 - many thanks for your info!